# Query GraphQL from React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, graphql

I have a form in React with an email and password input. And I need that when the "Login" button is pressed a request is sent to an Api Gateway that I have in GraphQL.

I have tried to create a function outside my component that receives as parameters the `email` and the `password` and uses the Hook `useQuery` inside the `urql` library. The problem is that I always get the error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: (You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM).
> You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
> You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem).

I tried adding the prefix `use` to the function name to declare it as a custom hook, however I still get the same error.

The full name of the function is `useLogin` and it does not return any element, it only makes the query and in case the credentials are correct, I store the token in the `localStorage` and redirect the user to the main page, otherwise, I launch a sweet alert mentioning that the user or the password is incorrect.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Or could someone recommend me the best way to perform and structure this query?

**P.S. I am not using the Apollo library because of a bug. When I reloaded the page and typed the username and password and pressed the "Login" button, it sent an "empty" query with the following form:**

```js
{data: undefined, loading: false, error: undefined, networkStatus: 7, refetch: ƒ, …}
called: false
client: ApolloClient {resetStoreCallbacks: Array(0), clearStoreCallbacks: Array(0), link: HttpLink, cache: InMemoryCache, disableNetworkFetches: false, …}
data: undefined
error: undefined
fetchMore: ƒ ()
loading: false
networkStatus: 7
observable: ObservableQuery {observers: Set(1), subscriptions: Set(0), queryInfo: QueryInfo, queryManager: QueryManager, _subscriber: ƒ, …}
previousData: undefined
refetch: ƒ ()
reobserve: ƒ ()
startPolling: ƒ ()
stopPolling: ƒ ()
subscribeToMore: ƒ ()
updateQuery: ƒ ()
variables: {}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Subsequently, if I pressed the button again (without changing the inputs) the request with the data was sent correctly.

Curiously, if I then type another user and password and press the button again, the data sent in the query are the same data of the previous query and not the data I just typed in the inputs.

Thanks for taking the time to read :3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific cause, but the "Invalid hook call" error and I are old friends. I can only recommend react's official documentation on the error, if you haven't considered it yet: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Having a brief look at the `package.json` of urql ([link](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/main/package.json)), it seems odd to me that react is not a peer dependency, which it probably should be. So, you could check if you have multiple copies of react in your bundle, because that would cause the error.